# Python - Why is every item in my list being overwritten by the final value of my while loop?

Tags: python, list, immutability, mutable

I am trying to calculate position from accelerometer values. To do this I am appending each acceleration output into a nested list along with a time stamp, I am then using those to calculate velocity and position. I am running into an issue where every value I appended in my velocity list is overwritten with the final velocity output in the while loop. Is there a way to keep a list of the velocity's value from each iteration of the loop without their value changing?

```
import time
from random import randint
acceleration_list = []
velocity_list = []
velocity = [[0,0,0],0]

index = 0

while index < 10:
    
    # Get current acceleration and append to list
    accel = [randint(-5,5),randint(-5,5),randint(-5,5)]              # Accelerometer Values 
    accel[1] -= 1                                                    # Subtract 1g from Y-value

    time_stamp = time.time()                                       # Time stamp
    curr_acceleration = [accel, time_stamp]                        # List to store accelerometer values + time stamp
    acceleration_list.append(curr_acceleration)                    # Add to total acceleration list
    # print(f"Acceleration values are: {acceleration_list}")
    time.sleep(0.025)
    # Calculate velocity using acceleration
    
    for i in range(3):
        if len(acceleration_list) > 1 and index > 0:                # Wait until we've done one iteration
            if abs(acceleration_list[index][0][i]) < 0.5:           # Filter out small values from the accelerometer
                acceleration_list[index][0][i] = 0.0
            # Previous Velocity + (Current Acceleration + Previous Acceleration / 2 ) * (Current Time - Previous Time) 
            velocity[0][i] = velocity_list[index-1][0][i] + ((acceleration_list[index][0][i] + acceleration_list[index-1][0][i])/2)*(acceleration_list[index][1] - acceleration_list[index-1][1])
    velocity[1] = acceleration_list[index][1]
    velocity_list.append(velocity)
    print(velocity)
    
    index += 1
print(velocity_list)
```

Comment: Do you think that `velocity` is a **different** list in each iteration of your loop?  Might it in fact be the **same** list instance in every iteration …

Comment: Each time through the loop, `velocity` is *the same object*. `.append` *does not copy* values; it puts *that object* into the list - the same object, multiple times. If you mutate that object, you see the change multiple times, because you are taking multiple looks at the same object.